# objective-c create a UIlabel with a hyperlink

Tags: objective-c, hyperlink, uilabel

what's the best way to create a label to link a web page?
thanks in advance!

Paolo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, instead of using  a label , you can use a button, set its title to the text you wanted to set for label & in the button action method you can link to the web page

Comment: thanks, but there's no way like the UITextView that convert the url into link?